# C# SetCursor back before last digit

Tags: c#, text, console, formatting

I am writing the progress at the end of a line, like so:

```
Some task ... 7%
Some task ... 23%
```

I have a function which just returns the progress string, e.g. "13%".
I like to use *Console.SetCursorPosition* to just overwrite the percentage string with the new one.
How can I set the cursor back, not to the beginning of the line, but before the percentage number starts?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your code is getting the value returned from the progress function, but you might be able to get away with something like this:

```
Console.Write($"Status of task ... {status}\r");
```